# Downloading a file from an API

Tags: javascript, file, download

I need to download the file coming from an API call, I've tried pretty anything, the last try was creating a blob with the "file" I receive in the API, how can I do it?

```
if(tipo_societa == "Società di Capitali"){
    id_visura = document.getElementById("id_visura").value;

    axios.get('https://visurecamerali.openapi.it/ordinaria-societa-capitale/' + id_visura + '/allegati', {
        headers:{
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + '{Token_Censored}'
        }
    })
    .then ( (res) => {

        data = res.data.data;

        console.log(data);
        
        /* Apri una nuova scheda con l'url */

        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.file]));
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', data.nome);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();

    })
}
```

the API respond with this:

> dimensione: 90800
> file: "UEsDBBQAAAAIABZc81ZGgkHU4mEBAOiFAQAcABwANjRiNTE0M(it's much more long)"
> nome: "64b51417f6ea811bc50ef8c9.zip"

Can someone help me?

I tried to make a blob to download the file, the download starts but the downloaded file isn't openable, like corrupted or things like this, theoretically this needs to download a zip that contains a PDF file.

Comment: What format does the API documentation say the file data will be provided in? At a guess, from what you've shown, it could be base64 perhaps, but I'm not sure. You really need to check the information, so we can be certain.

Comment: ADyson that's the problem, the docs don't say anything, for this call the explanation is literaly this: "This method allows you to download the document generated by the request passed id", nothing else, i contacted many times but no-one reply so idk what to do

Comment: Is there a link to the documentation where we can take a look at it as well?

Comment: sure, there: https://developers.openapi.it/categories/business_information/visurecamerali#/Società%20di%20Capitale/get_ordinaria_societa_capitale__id__allegati

Comment: `The docs don't say anything`...actually it says the type of that `file` property will be `string <byte>` (shown in the Response Schema section, if you expand the `data` object) at `https://developers.openapi.it/categories/business_information/visurecamerali#tag/Societa-di-Capitale/paths/~1ordinaria-societa-capitale~1{id}~1allegati/get`

Comment: honestly, i have absolutely no idea how to do that haha, i tried asking here for that

Comment: ok, thanks everyone, with your help i've resolved it with this: "element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;base64,' + data.file);", now all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end, I solved the problem by specifying that the string that came from the api was a base64, I leave the code below in case others run into the same problem

```
data = res.data.data;

console.log(data);
                    
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;base64,' + data.file);
element.setAttribute('download', data.nome);

element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);

element.click();

document.body.removeChild(element);
```

thank you very much whoever answered the question by letting me get to the solution ^^